# AzureのMachine Learningの学習モジュールの使い分けについて

Tags: 機械学習, azure

先週から機械学習を勉強し始めた、テクノロジーにかなり疎いOLです
基本的な質問ですみません

AzureのMachine Learningで来客数予測をするべく勉強を始めたのですが、
**学習モジュールの使い分け方法**がわからなくて行き詰まっております

同じ線形回帰であっても
Liner RegressionとBayesian Liner Regressionはどう使いわけするのか
（そもそも使い分けせず都度精度の確認をしなければいけないのか。。？）

その他のモジュールの’**こういうロジックを作る際はこのモジュール**’を
ご存知の方、もしくはまとめサイトなどございましたら
ご教授ください　　お願いします

[image: Azure ML 学習モジュール一覧]

Answer (score 2):

マイクロソフトも公式でチートシートを出していますよ！

https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/machine-learning/studio/algorithm-cheat-sheet

Answer (score 0):

自分も機械学習については始めたばかりですが、個人で機械学習を勉強するのであれば、多くのボランティアによって開発されている scikit-learn の方がお勧めです。scikit-learn であれば、[本家のマニュアル](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/basic/tutorial.html)も充実しているし、英語が苦手であれば日本語でかかれた参考書もあります。ググればWeb上にも情報が多いです。

scikit-learnではモジュールの使い分け方法については[本家のマニュアル](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/basic/tutorial.html)の[Choosing the right estimatorのページ](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/machine_learning_map/index.html)に次のような図でちゃんと説明があります。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

また、機械学習をするための環境構築が結構難しいのですが、[Google colab](https://colab.research.google.com/) を使うと機械学習用のモジュールがインストールされた Jupyter Notebook が無料ですぐに使えるのでこちらを使うとすぐに学習を始められます。

Answer (score 0):

2つの対処があるかと思います。

- 使い分けは一旦考慮せずに、複数の学習アルゴリズムを並列で使用して精度を確認する
- 個々の学習アルゴリズムを理解し、使用するデータの状態を確認してアルゴリズムを選択する

前者の場合、Azure Machine Learning Studio 上で Evaluate Model モジュールで算出させた指標値を比較し、どの学習アルゴリズムの精度がよかったかを見ていくことになります。

後者については、機械学習の理論に関して触れている書籍やサイトなどで学習を進めるのですが、実現したい内容に対して、どのアルゴリズムが適しているかどうかは「利用するデータの内容」に依存する部分があります。このため、同じ来客予測を2回作ったとしても、1回目と2回目でデータが異なれば（例えば、店舗前を通行する人数を入れるか入れないかという違い）、結果として適切な学習アルゴリズムが異なるケースもあります。